# Can a child have multiple parents in Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm working on a Sprite-Kit game and I have a menu that displays all the levels. I've created a locked image that I want to display on levels that are locked, below is the code:

```
SKSpriteNode *locked = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Locked.png"];
locked.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
locked.zPosition = 2.0;
locked.size = CGSizeMake(20, 20);
```

Then I want to display it on all the levels until they are unlocked. This is the code:

```
SKSpriteNode *level2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(40, 40)];
level2.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)-75, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+100);

[level2 addChild:locked];

[_levels addObject:level2];
[self addChild:level2];
```

But when I tried to display it on the third level:

```
SKSpriteNode *level3 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(40, 40)];
level3.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)-30, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+100);

[level3 addChild:locked];

[_levels addObject:level3];
[self addChild:level3];
```

I ran into an error because locked already had a parent.

**Can a child have multiple parents?** 
If so where am I going wrong?

Comment: You can have multiple parents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `SKNode` can only have one parent. (Its `parent` method can only return one thing, after all.)

It also conforms to NSCopying, which means you can copy a node if you need more than one with the `copy` method. So, you might try something like `[level3 addChild:[locked copy]];`

Comment: keep in mind that copying doesn't actually carry over every possible property of a SKNode (or SpriteNode). For instance, the name property would need to be set after the copy was made, if you wanted to refer to it again (for instance, to remove it later).